# Find Duplicates Outside of Selection/Highlight in the Same Column - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to Sort a column, 
then select a section of that column, 
and then Un-sort the column 
and let Excel find me all duplicates throughout that column that corresponds to any of the cells I selected before and preferably select them.

In short, I need Excel to find me any duplicates of any cell inside my selection, but OUTSIDE of my selection in the same column.

Example:

```
(34 SELECTED)    
(73 SELECTED)    
23    
86    
234    
21    
73    
853    
34    
11
```

OUTCOME:

```
(34 SELECTED)    
(73 SELECTED)    
23    
86    
234    
21    
(73 SELECTED)    
853    
(34 SELECTED)    
11
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: In your Outcome `34` & `73` appears twice since you are looking for Duplicates, also other values are unique,, I think you need to edit the post to clear your need !!

Comment: Hey Rajesh, thanks for getting back to me.

Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for; I want to find duplicate cells of the cells I have selected. In the example, I have selected 34 an 73, so I want to select ALL 34 and 73's in the whole column. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: What you are looking for is possible using Auto/Advance Filter also, VBA (Macro) can be used also ,, confirm can you handle VBA ?

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub SelectBySelection()
Dim tempArray()
Dim oneCell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim tempStr As String
Dim tempSelection As String

If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
tempArray = Selection.Value
For i = LBound(tempArray, 1) To UBound(tempArray, 1)
    tempStr = tempStr & Chr(0) & tempArray(i, 1)
Next
tempStr = tempStr & Chr(0)
For Each oneCell In Range(Selection.EntireColumn.End(xlUp), Selection.EntireColumn.End(xlDown))
    If InStr(tempStr, Chr(0) & oneCell.Value & Chr(0)) Then
        tempSelection = tempSelection & "," & oneCell.Address
    End If
Next
Range(Mid(tempSelection, 2)).Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: ,, this code is doing nothing,, OP wants to display Duplicates !!

Comment: @RajeshS This code selects all cells within a column which have the value equal to any value within starting selection - i.e. it selects all duplicates. In any case, the result is exactly what OP shows. Select first two cells, run the code - you will obtain 1,2,7 and 9 cells selected.

Comment: I've already tried it ,, then written comments,, finding no effect,, is this Standard module or  a Module ?

Comment: @RajeshS of course, Create - Module. All operations are performed on active sheet.

Comment: I've use as Module too,, but no effect!!

Comment: @RajeshS Screenshot added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92188/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-akina).

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoFilter

1. select 34 & 73 in AutoFilter
2. mark each cell with CTRL + single Mouse klick
3. select all in AutoFilter

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJJ3E.jpg]